Google authentication return null Principal
I'm trying to use Google authentication but it keep return null
this is my controller
{
    _logger.LogDebug("LoginGoogle initiated");
    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse")
    });
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
{
    _logger.LogDebug("GoogleResponse initiated");
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    if (result.Principal != null)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Principal found, extracting claims");
        var claims = result.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;

        if (claims != null)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Claims found");
            var claimValues = claims.Select(claim => new
            {
                claim.Issuer,
                claim.OriginalIssuer,
                claim.Type,
                claim.Value
            });

            _logger.LogDebug("Claim values: {@claimValues}", claimValues);
            // return Json(claimValues);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("No claims found");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("Principal is null");
    }

    // Handle the case where Principal or Claims are null
    _logger.LogDebug("Redirecting to Home due to missing Principal or Claims");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
}

this is my program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    googleOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
    googleOptions.Scope.Add("email");
});

console output
One thing i did is that my appsetting.json was copied from another project so that it matched the localhost port, which registered in console.cloud.google.com
I'm hoping anybody will have an answer for this problem because i can't find any.
